# splitting the result of ajax success message in 2 divs?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i use this function to send post request to PHP file

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "example.php",
                    type: "POST",     
                    data: { 
                        name: name,
                        address: adress
                    }, 
                    success: function(data) {
                         $("#name").html(data);

                    }          
                });
```

it works just fine and shows all of the success message (PHP file output) at the name div

what i need is to split this message so the success message for the name appear at "#name" and the one for the address appear at "#adress"

Comment: How is the return data look like.. Do console.log(data) in the call back..

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in this sort of situations is instead of getting one answer I use

```
    json_encode(array());
```

in my php file so I can have some sort of array like:

```
    responseArray=array('name'    => 'the name',
                        'address' => 'the address');
```

And instead of using $.ajax use $.getJSON in your js file

```
    $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        if(key=='name'){
          $('#namesdiv').html(val);
        } else {
          $('#addressdiv'.html(val);
        }
       }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, i have used it and it worked:

> $.ajax({
>
> ```
>                url: "example.php",
>
>                type: "POST",     
>
>                data: { 
>
>                    name: name,
>
>                    address: adress
>
>                }, 
>
>                success: function(data) {
>
>                     $("#name").html($(data).find('#your_element').html());
>
>                }          
>
>            });
> ```